# Agility vs. thread-safety

Tags: multithreading, winapi, com

I've recently learned that ["Agility doesn't imply thread safety."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/using-windows-runtime-objects-in-a-multithreaded-environment#objects-from-a-windows-runtime-component-that-is-written-in-c-or-visual-basic)  Can anyone explain how the two differ, and why one doesn't imply the other?  I'm particularly interested in learning about this in the context of C++ COM pointers, if that's at all relevant.  Thank you for any info.

Comment: Agile just means you *can* access (most almost any) objects from multiple threads, there's no protection (eg: synchronization, marshaling from apartments, etc) from COM. It doesn't mean it will work properly as expected. Any system/platform/os w/o COM is somehow agile...

Comment: Not relevant for COM, agility is a WinRT concept.  If an object is agile then it is *supposed* to be safe to use it from a worker thread.  The article points out that if the component is written in a managed language then you can't trust it.  The CLR just doesn't know and it gambles for agile.  Its been doing that for a very long time, the team that designed it was beaten up badly by Java in the middleware wars.